# Marketo Rest API for getting all email assets name contains <some_string>

Tags: marketo

Marketo Rest API for getting all email assets name contains <some_string>

I tried to use /rest/asset/v1/email/byName.json?name=2023 It's returning only emails those names are ending with 2023, not name contains.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you're using the API as opposed to the UI?

You should be able to search for such emails in Marketing activities, or define smart lists and settings in email-specific analytics reports.

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/marketo/using/product-docs/reporting/basic-reporting/report-activity/filter-assets-in-an-email-report.html

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/marketo/using/product-docs/marketo-engage-modern-ux/using-the-global-search.html